# Custom Bindings in MvvmCross Crosslight

Tags: mvvmcross

We're implementing our own cross platform framework using the binding capabilities of MvvmCross Core.
My question is how can custom bindings be registered within Mvx without the setup.
Custom binding used is an imeActionBinding similar to:
https://gist.github.com/slodge/8270923
attempted registration using:

```
Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered<IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry>(RegisterCustomBindings);

protected virtual void RegisterCustomBindings(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        EditTextImeActionBinding.Register(registry);
    }
```

Tried the same thing with project ChimpLight in the LightSetup:

```
  Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry>(new MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry());
  var customBindingRegistry = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry>();
  EditTextImeActionBinding.Register(customBindingRegistry);
```

xaml:

```
 <EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="Search"
  android:inputType="text"
  android:imeOptions="actionSearch"      
  local:MvxBind="Text LastName;ImeAction ResetCommand" />
```

no exceptions - but it seems the custom binding never gets loaded :|

what am I missing?

Comment: The `IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry` should already be registered as part of the binding setup - try using the existing binding registry instead of a new one - if that doesn't work, is there anything in the trace?

Comment: sorted - using the existing binding registry worked - thanks Stuart!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stuart for the simple answer: use the existing binding.
Using the N-30 Chimplight example code, the only added code to LightSetup class is:

```
        Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered<IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry>(registry =>
        {
            EditTextImeActionBinding.Register(registry);
        });
```